# About an "unusual" sentence structure?

Tags: grammar

In German, most sentences have a simple structure: subject, verb, object.

> Ich liebe dich.

But there are some verbs such as *gefallen* or *gelingen*, where this structure doesn't apply. Instead, the word order is *Es gefällt mir* or *Es gelingt mir*, with the object *es* in the first position, and the subject *mir* in the third position, and the DATIVE case. (The verb is still in the second spot.)

What is this kind of construction called in German?

Is it true that most of these verbs begin with *ge-*, and would there be a reason for this?

Are there more common examples of such constructions? How might I look them up?

Comment: Can you back up your claim about `most sentences` with some numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it true that most of these verbs begin with ge-, and would there be a reason for this?

For your examples, I always find a counterexample with 'miss-':

- es misslingt mir
- es missfällt mir

aber auch ein

- Dir misstrau ich

without `Dir getrau ich`, but `Dir vertrau ich`, which leads to many more constructs with `ver~`. But I didn't count them.

Other constructs:

- es reicht mir
- es langt mir
- es schmeckt mir
- es schmeichelt mir ...

without prefix.

Comment: OK, perhaps the "operative" words are "lingen" and "fällen," which can take on a either a positive "ge-" or a negative "miss-" prefix.

Comment: Interesting examples. Do at least some of them take ge- Gesmäckt, gelangen, or do I have wrong forms of your words?

Comment: Zu einer besseren Antwort hat es nicht gereicht. Nur über Übung gelangt man zur Meisterschaft. Es hat mir geschmeckt. Ich fühle mich geschmeichelt. - All examples need restructuring, to allow a prefix 'ge-', in case of `geschmeckt`, `geschmeichelt` and `gereicht` for the past tense. But I'm very unsure. I guess I'm quiete good in language usage and examples, but poor in rules, terms and explanation.

Answer (score 5):

The structure also applies to your samples. In "Es gefällt mir", *Es* is the subject, and *mir* is the object. You can even reverse the order to "Mir gefällt es", and still *es* is the subject in nominative and *Mir* is the object in dative case. There is no strict subject-predicate-object order in German.

Comment: exactly - for details on _Wortstellung_, see [here](http://canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/index.html) and [here](http://deutsch.lingo4u.de/grammatik/satzbau/wortstellung).

Comment: No, this answer is a little disingenuous. Tom has a legitimate question which you are turning around on a technicality. This structure is indeed a bit peculiar, and the fact that we cannot easily and precisely describe what that structure is, does not make it any less so.

Comment: "There is no strict subject-predicate-object order in German." Sums it up nicely.